# Browser using c# in windows form applications

Tags: c#, html, windows, forms, browser

i have developed a browser using c# in windows form applications, now i want to put a button to store html code in a text document, how do i do that, thanks

```
namespace browser
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            browser.Refresh();
        }

        private void home_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            browser.GoHome(); 
        }

        private void back_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (browser.CanGoBack)
            {
                browser.GoBack();
            }
        }

        private void forward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (browser.CanGoForward)
            {
                browser.GoForward();
            }
        }

        private void stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            browser.Stop();
        }

        private void go_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = textBox.Text.Trim();
            browser.Navigate(url);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to save html code of that website ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http; 

WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://yourwebsite.com");
req.Method = "GET";

string source;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
{
    source = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test.txt");
file.WriteLine(source);

file.Close();
```

Comment: thanks , i have an another question. suppose i have opened www.google.com in c# browser, how do i enter some string and click search button using code

Comment: post that as another question rather linking with same question..thank you

Comment: visual studio is raising an error with "using System.Net.Http;"

Comment: imported that reference